Colocar fecha actual en un campo de formulario tipo date
estoy creando un plugin para wordpress, y me lié con esto.

Cuando quiero adicionar un registro, lanzo una ventana modal, donde coloco el formulario con los datos que quiero recolectar.
Uno de los campos es de tipo fecha, y quiero que aparezca la fecha actual del sistema, y luego enfocar el ingreso en el siguiente campo.

ya pude obtener la fecha

pero aún no puedo hacer que aparezca en el campo de fecha :(

y mi código va así.

Les agradezco mucho su apoyo!

Hola, agradecería que leas [ask] y como hacer un [example]

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
